# Cannot connect to Database under a prefix in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

Hi there I created a database from Cpanel and it was put under a prefix in phpMyAdmin.

[image]

I was expecting this structure.

[image]

I have tried all my best to connect to it but failed.
This is my connection file:

```
$dbname="hrmauorg_another";
$server="hrmau.org.***";
$username="hrmauorg_***";
$password="***************";
$con = mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
   echo mysqli_connect_error();
}else{
   echo 'connected';
}
```

Could it be the reason why am failing to connect. Thanks for your help in advance.....

Comment: I think you cannot change Cpanel pre-fix text for a database, you have to go with it. moreover you can reach hosting service to verify that.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem I changed `$server = localhost`.
In some other cases I could use the domain name and it could work. I can't tell why it failed today.